# Trouble understanding diode circuit problem

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, diodes, homework

I am having trouble understanding a diode circuit problem. I dont understand which direction the current will flow. I think for part a, Vout will be 9.3 V. But for part b, I'm unsure of how to get +6.2 V going into D1. I am just unsure of how to tackle this problem. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to re-write this circuit so it is in the form of a "loop"? I am having trouble understanding which way current will flow in a straight line

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @winny Yes homework. I have tried solving in MultiSIM but I don't think it's accurate because I'm not sure what diode to use. Tried KCL and got iD1=0.124mA, iD2=0.434mA, iD3=0.434mA, and the current through the 5KOhm resistor is 0.992mA. This would make Vout 4.96V

Comment: Show us your work when tried to solve the problem using KCL, and any other attemps that you made.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you reorganise it like this does it make it any easier?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8bIQG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. What's the voltage at the bottom of each diode?*

Comment: I believe the voltage at the bottom of each diode would be V - 0.7V. So 4.8V, 9.3V, and 9.3V.

Comment: "2 out of 3 ain't bad." How did you get 4.8 V?

Comment: It's 0V I lied. I was doing 5.5-0.7

Comment: Nope. If D1 is forward biased what is the voltage at the junction of D1 and R1?

Comment: If D1 is forward biased, the voltage at that junction would have to be 6.2V (0.7V greater than +5.5V on the other side)

Comment: Right. Now you need to figure out if D1 ***is*** forward biased. Remove it for a minute and calculate Vout to see if it is more or less than 6.2 V for question a).